# PHP: Extracting values from the keys of array

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
$arrmixData = array();
$arrmixData['maintenance_request'] = array(
'is_charge_post' => '1',
'is_material_post' => '1',
 'sub_maintenance_request_123456'=> array(
    'is_complete_sub_task' => '0'
    ),
'sub_maintenance_request_123465'=> array(
    'is_complete_sub_task' => '1'
    ));
```

After displaying the array it shows -

```
Array(
[maintenance_request] => Array
    (
        [is_charge_post] => 1
        [is_material_post] => 1
        [sub_maintenance_request_123456] => Array
            (
                [is_complete_sub_task] => 0
            )

        [sub_maintenance_request_123465] => Array
            (
                [is_complete_sub_task] => 1
            )

    ))
```

I want only id from the key "sub_maintenanace_request_". I tried for explode but its not work. Any suggestions.

Expected output:

```
$arrSubIds = (123456,123465);
```

Answer (score 2):

[**Code Snippet**](https://eval.in/782822)

You can iterate on each key and check if key has 'sub_maintenance_request' or not. Further you check if it has digit or not, if it has digit you can store matched digit.

`$result` has the final result.

**Try this :**

```
$arrmixData = array();
$arrmixData['maintenance_request'] = array(
    'is_charge_post' => '1',
    'is_material_post' => '1',
    'sub_maintenance_request_123456'=> array(
        'is_complete_sub_task' => '0'
    ),
    'sub_maintenance_request_123465'=> array(
        'is_complete_sub_task' => '1'
        )
    );
$result = array();
//Itetrate on each key
foreach($arrmixData['maintenance_request'] as $key=> $value){
    //check if key has 'sub_maintenance_request_' in it or not
    if (strpos($key, 'sub_maintenance_request_') !== false) {
        //check if key contains digits if yes then store them in $result
        if (preg_match('#(\d+)$#', $key, $matches)) {
            $result[] = array_shift( $matches );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @Rizier123 thanks.. I'll edit and improve my answer.

Answer (score 1):

use `Explode` and `strpos`

1) strpos to check current key is `sub_maintenance_request_` or not

2) if it's `sub_maintenance_request_` then use explode by `"_"`underscore.

3) Get the last value from exploded array using `array_pop()`

```
<?php

$arrSubIds=array();
foreach($arrmixData['maintenance_request'] as $key=>$row)
{

   if(strpos($key, 'sub_maintenance_request_') !== false)
   {
      $arrSubIds[] = array_pop(explode('_',$key)); 

   }

}

print_r($arrSubIds);

?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123456
    [1] => 123465
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we are using `strpos` function to retrieve position of `substring` with in a string and  `ltrim` function to trim a `substring` from the left.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/782816)

```
<?php

$arrmixData = array();
$arrmixData['maintenance_request'] = array(
    'is_charge_post' => '1',
    'is_material_post' => '1',
    'sub_maintenance_request_123456' => array(
        'is_complete_sub_task' => '0'
    ),
    'sub_maintenance_request_123465' => array(
        'is_complete_sub_task' => '1'
        ));
$result=array();
foreach($arrmixData["maintenance_request"] as $key => $value)
{
    if(strpos($key, "sub_maintenance_request_")===0)//getting the position of substring
    {
        $result[]=ltrim($key,"sub_maintenance_request_");trimmed substring to retrieve last digits
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123456
    [1] => 123465
)
```